# How do I create references (as web URL Links) to specific emails in my Gmail account?

Tags: gmail, url, links, productivity

I want to create references (as web URL Links) to specific emails in my Gmail account so I can refer back to them quickly eg. Requests for specific features from clients that might be scattered across multiple email conversations. Is there a quick way to do this?

Finding the specific email is particularly problematic in long threaded conversations.

I have tried a few things, looked for various solutions and experimented with a few google marketplace extensions and so far drawn a blank. If all else fails, I have one stop gap solution around searches that might sort of work I think but I thought I'd throw it out to the wider community first before falling back on that.